# iOS Auto-Renewable Subscriptions Free Trial Not Being Indicated

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, trial, auto-renewable

I am having some issues adding a free trial to an existing Auto-Renewable IAP. From what I understand, you only need to add a "free trial" duration in iTunesConnect in your IAP for this to work. but I am not seeing any update in the description of the purchase indicating the free trial. When looking at other apps that do offer a free trial, the apple subscription dialog that pops up indicates:

```
Subscription Terms
Subscribe to <IAP NAME>. this subscription will start with a free trial lasting <TRIAL DURATION> after which youy will be charged <PRICE> on a <Duration> basis
```

while my own dialog still shows (not indicating that there is a free trial):

```
Subscription Terms
Subscrube to <IAP NAME>. This subscription will automatically renew every year for <PRICE>
```

Am I missing something in iTunes connect? Do I need to enable free trials another way?

What I have tried:

1. Using a sandbox account with an Auto-Renewable Sub that is not
   cleared for sale
2. Using a fresh iTunes account on an Auto-Renewable
       Sub that is cleared for sale and I have temporarily added the free
       trial duration in iTunes connect
3. Using a sandbox account on an Auto-Renewable Sub that is cleared for
           sale and I have temporarily added the free trial duration in iTunes
           connect

Comment: Have you tried making the purchase with a fresh sandbox account for the products with trial period enabled?

Comment: @SamuellJackson did you find a fix for this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. In my case, it even didn't show me the Subscription Terms alert only the Subscription Confirmation.

The problem seems to be with the Sandbox Testing account rather than with the implementation. You probably didn't have the trial set up in your IAP and then you created Sandbox tester and tested it like this. Then you added the free trial to the IAP, but the Sandbox tester has in cache or somewhere that this IAP doesn't have trial.

QUICK FIX: Create a new Sandbox Tester in iTunesConnect.